# How to configure apache proxy with 2 contexts: "/" and "/dev"

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-ajp

I have 2 AJP services running in my server and a Apache 2.4 to proxy then.

I want to map this:

```
# in-development environment
<Location "/dev">
    ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:3001/dev/
</Location>

# in production environment
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:3000/
</Location>
```

But when I access http://myserver/dev it proxies to `ajp://127.0.0.1:3000/` instead of `ajp://127.0.0.1:3001/`.

Comment: Remove Location and try like this ProxyPass /dev ajp://127.0.0.1:3001/dev

Comment: @VaibhavPanmand and the other proxy "/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way [Overlapping Webspace](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#file-and-web) is handled by the `<Location>` directive. As noted in the Apache documentation,

> In order to have two overlapping URLs one has to consider the order in which certain sections or directives are evaluated. For `<Location>` this would be:

```
<Location "/foo">
</Location>
<Location "/foo/bar">
</Location>
```